# Why cant swif3 initialize Array of Nested class the usual way?

Tags: arrays, swift, types

Let me share the code.

```
public class A {
    public class B { }
}
```

Now when i want to make a array of type B. I would natuarally use this syntax.

```
let intarr = [Int]()
let c = [A.B]()         //cannot call value of non-function type A.B.Type
```

However, swift wont allow me to use array the above way. But, the following 2 ways doesnot error.

```
let c1 = Array<A.B>()
let c2: [A.B] = []
```

The question now is: why is the first expression  `let c = [A.B]()` not valid?